# Cannot install Helm chart when accessing GKE cluster directly

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I've set up a basic GKE cluster using Autopilot settings. I am able to install Helm charts on it using kubectl with proper kubeconfig pointing to the GKE cluster.

I'd like to do the same without the kubeconfig, by providing the cluster details with relevant parameters.
To do that I'm running a docker container using **alpine/helm** image and passing the paramtrised command which looks like this:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/chart alpine/helm install <my_chart_name> /chart --kube-apiserver <cluster_endpoint> --kube-ca-file /chart/<cluster_certificate_file> --kube-as-user <my_gke_cluster_username> --kube-token <token>
```

unfortunately it returns :

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "http://<cluster_endpoint>/version": dial tcp <cluster_endpoint>:80: i/o timeout
```

Is this even doable with GKE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! A more experienced colleague has found the solution.

1. I should have used the address including "http://" protocol specification. That however still kept returning "Kubernetes cluster unreachable: " error, with "unknown" details instead.
2. I had been using incorect username. Instead the one from kubeconfig file, a new service account should be created and its name used instead in a form `system:serviceaccount:<namespace>:<service_account>`. However that would not alter the error either.
3. The service account lacked proper role, following command did the job: `kubectl create rolebinding  --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=<namespace>:<service_account>`. Ofc, **cluster-admin** might now be the role we want to give away freely.